# PHP Multidimensional Array First Object

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in PHP that looks like

```
Array ( [123654] => Array ( [0] => 123456789123456789 [1] => 1 [2] => 06/24/2011 [3] => 06/24/2012 [4] => 12355.44 [5] => 55321.55 ) )
```

I know in javascript I could access the data I need by doing array[0][0], how would I go about doing this in PHP. It is the 123456789123456789 value that I'm looking at getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the exact keys, you could do something like this:

```
$a = array_values($my_array);
$b = array_values($a[0]);
echo $b[0];
```

`array_values` replaces the keys by simple numbers from `0` to `n-1` (where `n` is the count of values), by that you can access your desired value with the indexes [0][0]. See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
array_slice($array, 0, 1);
```

http://php.net/array_slice

Comment: @MartinMatysiak This is not explicit enough. If his array keys change or elements within the array or sub-array are re-arranged, this will get the wrong values.

Comment: Well, he wants the first value of the first sub-array, doesn't he? If the order changes, than another array or value is the respective first one, so that should be written. At least that is how I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.org/YXu6884R

Here you go. See above for proof. The methodology from @azat is not explicit enough and is prone to risk if the elements of the array or sub array are re-arranged or if the key value for the super array changes.

```
$my_array = array( 123654 => array( 0 => '123456789123456789', 1 => '1', 2 => '06/24/2011', 3 => '06/24/2012', 4 => '12355.44', 5 => '55321.55' ) );

echo $my_array['123654'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$first = array_shift(array_values($array));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php